# Mouse Freeze and Help window auto launch

Tags: mouse, freeze, cursor

I have a Toshiba Satellite laptop. I am facing a unique problem here. My laptop mouse pointer will freeze automatically accompanied by auto launch of the help screen of the application i am viewing at that time. So if i am viewing Chrome, Chrome help will launch; If using Windows Explorer, Windows Help will launch; If using vlc, the vlc help will launch. The only way i can get back the mouse is clicking on the Windows button on which the START window opens and i get back control of the mouse. 
Even stranger is that if even if i plug in an external mouse, laptop mouse still freezes and help window opens. The external mouse works (i.e only moves on screen) but i cant go to any screen unless i close the help window. Whenever i click on other tabs or windows the system does nothing and stays in the Help window.

Pls help. I am at my wits end.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure all your drivers are up to date. If they are not they can cause some issues.
If you are on windows 10, 8.1, or 8 (don't know about windows 7) press the start key and search "Device Drivers" and then sift through to find your mouse drivers right click and press Update (You may need to go into the properties and then look for update).